# Idea: how can I hide the VCS changes markers in the right margin

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to hide the marker stripes in the right margin of intellij idea.

I tried whith:

```
settings -> Editor -> Colors and Fonts -> General
```

but it is not possible to check/uncheck "Error stripe Mark" in "Added lines" or "Modified lines".

I also tried to put white colors in "stripe mark color" in

```
settings -> Editor -> Colors and Fonts -> Diff
```

but the stripe is still present.

Do you know if it's possible to manage that without removing VCS support for the project?

Answer (score 7):

There is now a setting as of IntelliJ IDEA 15 142.3728 (released as EAP in August 2015).

In preferences, go to `Editor -> General` and untick `Highlight modified lines in gutter`.

Comment: Doing this only hides markers on left gutter. Right side gutter still has the markers.

Comment: As @rpr mentions, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

**PhpStorm 2022**

Uncheck the tick here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use version 12.1.4

Easiest way I've found is by right-clicking on the marker at the top of the margin.

Click "Customize Highlighting level" and bring the slider down "syntax".

This may also help:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editor-appearance.html

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ 14.

In dark theme, the change marker at right margin is very eye-distracting. The real problem is we can not close it.

Go to `Editor -> Colors and Fonts -> General` and
find:

- `deleted line in gutter`
- `added line in gutter`
- `modified line in gutter`

Change to color you like.

Here is the official doc about [changes marker](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-change-markers-to-view-and-navigate-through-changes-in-the-editor.html).

Comment: That link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. Set `Editor > General > Error highlighting > Error stripe mark min height (pixels)` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2024 on Android Studio (an IntelliJ variant), here's what I had to do to get rid of the annoying version control marks in the right-hand scrollbar (aka Error stripe mark area).  Some of the previous answers address the marks in the gutter, which is to the LEFT of the text/editor area (not what the original poster was asking).

It's *really* convenient to know the background color of the right-hand scrollbar.  The trick to figuring that out is below (for those of you who don't already have that info at hand).

Pull up settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Diff & Merge (see the cyan highlight in the graphic below).

Open the "Changed Lines" so that the different types of changes are revealed.

Unfortunately you cannot simply disable the "Error stripe mark" like you can with most custom colors.  But you can make the error stripe *the exact same color as the background*.  This effectively makes the stripe invisible.

Do this for each version control item you no longer want to see in the right-hand scrollbar area.

[image: where to find the error stripe mark for version control]

### But what is the background color?

Here's the recipe to figure out what the background color is in the right-hand scrollbar area.

Navigate to settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General (see the second graphic below).

In the list of all the things to set colors for, select Editor -> Breadcrumbs -> Current.

The color of the background should be listed.  For my color scheme it's `434C5E`.

I recommend copying the color (you have to open the color picker first, sigh) and then going back to the settings above and change the error stripes marks to this color.

And voila, no more annoying colors!

[image]