# How to remove green/yellow vertical line at code-folding area in MaterialUI Theme?

Tags: intellij-idea

I just installed the popular [Material Theme UI EAP](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9377-material-theme-ui-eap) from the IntelliJ website. But i'm getting distracted by the green and yellow vertical lines in the theme. How do i remove them?

Photo attached: [image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29668881/104891

Comment: doesn't seem to be it